# Please check my proof and let me know if incorrect.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\tan x}= \sin(x)\cos(x)$$

i did the following working on LHS:
$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{\tan x}=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(x)}{\tan x}=\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
i need to confirm that $$\frac{\sin x}{\tan x}=\cos(x)$$

Comment: If you remember the definition of $\tan x$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, I think you'll be able to confirm your last step.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\frac{\sin x}{\tan x} = \frac{\sin x} {\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} = \frac{ \sin x \cos x}{\sin x} = \cos x$$